# How to reverse the content of binary file?

Tags: binary

I was solving a challenge where I found a **data file** with no file extension. The `file` command shows that it is a `data file (application/octet-stream)`. The `hd` command shows **GNP.** in the last line. So if I reverse this file then I will get the **.PNG** format file, I searched everywhere but I didn't find a solution explaining how to reverse the content of a binary file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `xxd` (from `vim`) and `tac` (from GNU coreutils, also `tail -r` on some systems):

```
< file.gnp xxd -p -c1 | tac | xxd -p -r > file.png
```

Comment: Is there any way for this to be combined with https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2237/10649? I tried all kind of combinations with no luck :(

Comment: This is not a solution because it will mirror all the file.

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil, _mirroring all the file_ was what the OP is asking for here? What else would you want it to do?

Answer (score 5):

In `zsh` (the only shell that can internally deal with binary data (unless you want to consider [ksh93's base64 encoding approach](/a/416587))):

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
(LC_ALL=C; printf %s ${(s::Oa)mapfile[file.gnp]} > file.png)
```

- `LC_ALL=C`: characters are bytes
- `$mapfile[file.gnp]`: content of `file.gnp` file
- `s::`: split the string into its byte constituents
- `Oa`: reverse `O`rder on `a`rray subscript that array

Comment: `zsh` is not the only shell that can handle binary data.

Answer (score 3):

With perl:

```
perl -0777pe '$_=reverse $_'  [input_file]
```

Performance test:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/a bs=1M count=1
LC_ALL=C tac -rs $'.\\|\n' /tmp/a > /tmp/r

time perl -0777pe '$_=reverse $_' /tmp/a         | diff -q - /tmp/r
time xxd -p -c1 /tmp/a | tac | xxd -p -r         | diff -q - /tmp/r
time perl -0777 -F -ape '$_=reverse@F' /tmp/a    | diff -q - /tmp/r
time LC_ALL=C tac -rs $'.\\|\n' /tmp/a           | diff -q - /tmp/r
```

Result:

- Tested locally: my solution is the fastest, `perl -0777 -F` is the slowest.
- Tested on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY@xDoIwEIZ3nuIfSJgqMjHVaEiY8A1ISKElkgjUthCGvns1KKiDctNd7u6770qmL85xjqamIRdjOCjW8b5F/6hNK0OGUtPojKofOkMjL0uKU5bRBIZVIErDD3Z5bvMuwGv@8EyU55mmFZBCXUH2cRxLgcAvqBKjUFrAL9aVJSx4U9cgN5AFMjOmiYNIkCpaNux8364dtcl4e4CkIOzb5ph@yvxibD@Pfx7O3QE): my solution is the fastest, `xxd` is the slowest.

Note: the time `diff` runs should be the same for all solutions, as the output should be the same.

Comment: I've deleted my `perl` one. I hadn't realised at the time `reverse` could reverse strings as well, so doing that splitting didn't make much sense and your version is much much better.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of reversing a binary file using `ksh93`.  I have left the code "loose" to make it easier to understand.

```
#!/bin/ksh93

typeset -b byte

redirect 3< image.gpj || exit 1

eof=$(3<#((EOF)))

read -r -u 3 -N 1 byte
printf "%B" byte > image.jpg
3<#((CUR - 1))

while (( $(3<#) > 0 ))
do
    read -r -u 3 -N 1 byte
    printf "%B" byte >> image.jpg
    3<#((CUR - 2))
done

read -r -u 3 -N 1 byte
printf "%B" byte >> image.jpg

redirect 3<&- || echo 'cannot close FD 3'

exit 0
```

Comment: nice. That's the only answer so far that doesn't involve storing the whole file in memory. However, it's terribly inefficient in that it makes several system calls for each byte of the file (and conversions to/from base64), so wouldn't be suitable for files that don't fit in memory  either. On my machine, it processes files at about 10KB/s

Comment: Note that the first `read` above should read nothing as it's done at the end of the file.

Comment: Trying to understand why it was so slow, I tried running it under `strace` and `ksh93` seems to be behaving very weirdly, where it seeks all over the place within the file and reads large amounts at the time. Maybe a variant of https://github.com/att/ast/issues/15

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. No mystery as to why it is relatively slow.  Within the loop it has to seek backwards each time it reads a byte. This can easily be significantly reduced by a factor of 20 or even more by reading and writing more than one byte at a time.   The write side of things can similarly be optimized.  Lots of other techniques are available to further speed things up.   I will leave that exercise up to you.

Comment: Try `strace` on the script to see what I mean. `ksh93` reads the files thousands of times over. For instance, before reading the first byte, it seeks 64KiB off the end of the file, reads 64KiB, then seeks before the last byte and reads 1 byte and does something similar for every byte. Note that what you can do with those base64 encoded strings is limited, so if you read more than one byte at a time, it's going to be more difficult to extract the individual bytes of that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
tac -rs '.' input.gnp > output.png
```

The idea is to force 'tac' using any character as separator.
I tried that on a binary file and it seemed to work but any confirmation would be appreciated.

Main advantage is that it does not load file into memory.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (here with GNU `tac` 8.28) when the input contains newline characters. `printf '1\n2' | tac -rs . | od -vAn -tc` outputs `\n 2 1` instead of `2 \n 1`. You'd also need `LC_ALL=C` or `.` could match multi-byte characters.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C tac -rs $'.\\|\n'` seems to work though.